# Tibco Unit Testing tools

Tags: unit-testing, frameworks, tibco, businessworks

Does anyone know what unit testing tools are available when developing Tibco processes?

In the next few months I'll be working on a Tibco project and I'm trying to find any existing unit testing frameworks that might make the job easier to build with a TDD approach.

Thus far, the only one I've been able to locate is called [BWUnit](http://windyroad.org/software/bwunit/). It seems ok but its currently in beta and its commercial software. If possible I'd like to use an open source tool but as long as it is able to do a good job I'd be happy.

So does anyone know of any other unit testing tools for Tibco development?

Also, does anyone have any experience with BWUnit? How useful is/was it?

Comment: Update: BWUnit is now out of beta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For BW projects, I cooked my own Unit Test framework based on BW Processes itself. So the automated tests and validations are coded in the TIBCO project itself.

For AMX projects I recommend SOAPUI for automated testing of your services. However, I coded all the unit tests in the underlying language, in my case Java, using JUnit. The Implementation classes under the components reference each other directly in the unit tests, bypassing the AMX code doing the messaging.

Comment: This is what I've ended up having to do because I can't affort the expensive BWUnit licence.

Comment: That solution works pretty good for us.
The nature of the Designer Tester replaces the JUnit graphic interface nicely. 

I'm writing a detail description of this solution in my blog, once I finish it I'll post a link to it here.

Comment: @meziod. If you are still interested in BWUnit, give us yell via the support link on the BWUnit page and we'll see if we can work something out for you.

Comment: it may be too late but please check my comment about bw-test on nicosommi.com it's free and open source

Answer (score 4):

I've had great success creating a soap interface layer for each of my processes (taking in the same arguments) and leveraging [SoapUI](http://soapui.org) to do all the testing driven from a few database tables.

Edit:

What I described is pretty much how BWUnit is working: it creates a web service interface around each of your processes (maybe with a little less manual work, but same concept.)

> Test Input (SoapUI) -> Testable Interface (soap/ems/etc) -> Existing process -> Exit Interface -> Assertions (SoapUI)

You could do the testing within tibco itself, with files, RV, JMS, or any input for that matter, except you're writing all the test assertion code yourself rather than using an existing tool that has it all built in. You can then rely on SoapUI to generate all your JUnit reports etc.

If you want to get really fancy, you can add a soapui target to your build script to include the unit tests and/or functional tests for each build once it's deployed.

Comment: What does that have to do with Unit Testing Tibco processes?

Comment: See edit - not sure how it's not unit testing the processes. What's not making sense?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you had initially written. You're update clarified a few things....

Answer (score 3):

Deopends on the protocol used (what is used).  Racoon and SoapUI has been mentioned. With them you can test on a "per module" level. That is Component or System tests. Especially usful for performance tests. However this is the most common way to test tibco components.

I will have a look at the BWUnit, looks interesting and integrated with CI Servers (I have built a similar tool in a project). A flaw of this approch may be that TIBCO systems usually are composed of different tools and not only BW, this means that Java components, C++ servers and so fort is used to for the total system.

There is also a Commercial tool called GHTester (http://www.greenhatconsulting.com/ghtester/)

If you are using RV you might have a look at http://www.rvsnoop.org/ to capture the messages in a replayable format for free (OSS tool that I started)

Answer (score 3):

Trying to do a methodology like TDD using soap UI would  not be very effective.  I have used This for BW and you do not get the same level of granularity and comfort from a full unit test suite.  BWUnit is a good tool, and if you have a good relationship with your TIbco PSG guys you may be able to get TibUnit which is a PSG Ware like CLE.

We've also come up with a plan to use an external Unit test framework like .net and then use a controller pattern to swap out processes using Dynamic Process override flag.  So esentaially we'd have a control channel that would say something like

Control
   - Process 1 Override
             -/Processes/SomeProcess.process
   - Process 2 Override
             {Blank}

so in your unit test you would be able in your setup to call BW using your control channel (EMS or HTTP) and tell it to load a different process.  While this works its still a hack because of the limited functionality of Designer.

We've also looked at Service Grid and BWSE and that didn't appear to give us anything more.  Actually a little more limiting.

Answer (score 2):

There's an old framework called [Raccoon](http://raccoonfwk.sourceforge.net/) built above Tibco ActiveEnterprise.

It has a component for unit testing called [UiTest](http://raccoonfwk.sourceforge.net/tibco/uiTest.html) focused on RendezVous messaging.

It doesn't seem to have too much activity lately, though.

Answer (score 2):

With BW-TEST you can practice TDD and add your projects to your CI
Check it out on http://nicosommi.com/?p=209

It's open source

Answer (score 1):

[IBM RIT](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rithelp/v8r5m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.rit.accessibility.doc/helpindex_rit.html) is very good tool to work on this kind of scenarios, it can help you to assert different scenarios and also to evaluate code coverage.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend IBM RIT. it is part of IBM RTW stack. You can use it in TDD and CI/CD models of delivery easily.